# how to use only one html file to show different but similar contents

Tags: javascript, html

I created a hospital.js file which include an array contains all the information needed, then i used this hospital.js file to create a table in my hospital.html to show a list of all hospitals, now I want to add links to each cell of the table, when I click a hospital's name, it will go to a new detailPage.html which will show detail information of this hospital.

but now I can only open same detailPage no matter which hospital i click, can i only use this detailPage.html to show different hospital's information after I click corresponding hospitals? since the format of detailPage is same, the only difference is their name, address, tel, etc.  If so, how can I do it?

[list of hospital in hospital.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6j4E.png)

[hospital.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP23w.png)

[create table in hospital.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHOQa.png)

[javascript codes to create table in hospital.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxvEy.png)

[detailPage.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdCxI.png)

[detailPage html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ6ne.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for the future endeavor at Stack overflow. Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community  -Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Variable values ​​must be injected into the html file. Simply you can use html query string to pass variables into the html file like below.

Example Html(test.html)

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
      document.body.innerHTML = `
      <h1>${urlParams.get('name')}</h1>
      <h1>${urlParams.get('address')}</h1>
      <h1>${urlParams.get('tel')}</h1>
      `
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Example link to access it:  "test.html?name=apple&address=home&tel=1234"

(Note, Internet Exploere doesn't support `URLSearchParams`. So you want your html available for all browser, please add your own function(polyfill) to get query string)

```
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};
```

Usage

```
getUrlParameter('name') // => apple
```